# Transpose df columns based on the column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below and I would like to transpose the df based on the column Names

I want transpose all the coumns that has _1,_2,_3 & _4. I have 100+ Values in my df, Below is the example data.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
        # One Id Column
        'id':[1],
        
        #Other columns
        'c1':['1c'],
        'c2':['2c'],
        'c3':['3c'],
        
        #IC indicator
        'oc_1':[1],
        'oc_2':[0],
        'oc_3':[1],
        'oc_4':[1],
        
        #GC Indicator
        'gc_1':['T1'],
        'gc_2':['T2'],
        'gc_3':['T3'],
        'gc_4':['T4'],
        
        #PF Indicator
        'pf_1':['PF1'],
        'pf_2':['PF2'],
        'pf_3':['PF3'],
        'pf_4':['PF4'],
        
        #Values
        'V1_1':[11],
        'V1_2':[12],
        'V1_3':[13],
        'V1_4':[14],
        
        'S1_1':[21],
        'S1_2':[22],
        'S1_3':[23],
        'S1_4':[24]
        
        }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I need to transpose this df as below output

[image]

I tried below code:

```
standard_cols = ['id','c1','c2','c3']
value_cols = ['V1_1','V1_2','V1_3','V1_4','S1_1','S1_2','S1_3','S1_4']
result_cols = standard_cols+['OC','GC','PF','Var','value']

melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=standard_cols + ['oc_1','oc_2','oc_3','oc_4','gc_1','gc_2','gc_3','gc_4','pf_1','pf_2','pf_3','pf_4'],
                    value_vars=value_cols,var_name='Var',value_name='value')

print(melted_df)
```

Comment: Your image and the dataframe constructor don't match. Are the final columns `v1` or `v1_1`?

Comment: @mozway sorry for the confusion. Updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first reshape with [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
standard_cols = ['id','c1','c2','c3']
value_cols = ['V1','S1']
result_cols = ['OC','GC','PF']

result_cols = [c.lower() for c in result_cols]

out = (pd
  .wide_to_long(
      df, i=standard_cols,
      stubnames=result_cols+value_cols,
      j='j', sep='_')
  .reset_index()
  .melt(standard_cols+result_cols+['j'],
        var_name='VAR', value_name='Value')
  .assign(VAR=lambda d: d['VAR']+'_'+d.pop('j').astype('str'))
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   id  c1  c2  c3  oc  gc   pf   VAR  Value
0   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T1  PF1  V1_1     11
1   1  1c  2c  3c   0  T2  PF2  V1_2     12
2   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T3  PF3  V1_3     13
3   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T4  PF4  V1_4     14
4   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T1  PF1  S1_1     21
5   1  1c  2c  3c   0  T2  PF2  S1_2     22
6   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T3  PF3  S1_3     23
7   1  1c  2c  3c   1  T4  PF4  S1_4     24
```

Comment: Can you help me how to handle if we have multiple '_' in the column Name. `Eg: S1_S_1` so

Comment: @RoshanNuvvula you can tune the `suffix` parameter in `wide_to_long`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Transpose the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

# Separate processing for VAR field
df_var = df[df.index.str.contains(r"^[VS]")].copy()
df_var[0] = df_var.index
df_var.index = ['VAR'] * len(df_var)

# Replace indexes starting with V and S with 'Value'
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r"^[VS].*", "Value", regex=True)

# Concatenate the VAR field back to the DataFrame
df = pd.concat((df, df_var))

# Extract values before '_' from the index
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.split("_")[0])

# Group and transform into lists
grouped = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False)[0].apply(list)

# Expand each group's data using np.pad with 'wrap' parameter to match the maximum length
result = grouped.apply(lambda x: np.pad(x, (0, len(df_var) - len(x)), "wrap")).apply(pd.Series).T
result
```